# Process to make a build in one step using Xcode + SVN / Git

Tags: xcode, git, svn, version-control

We have several teams running iOS projects and using SVN/Git for version control, now i need to know the process how to make a build in one step (to make the app for release) using Xcode and SVN/Git.

Need to know #

- how others are doing this (one step build to release)
- What is the best practice (several teams, SVN or Git)